# How to import fonts in React Native Typescript?

Tags: react-native

as in topic. I am trying to use fonts in react native with typescript if it matters.

I prepared small snippet and I would like to know what am I doing wrong? Why is it so complicated and anywhere I can not find clear answer.

```
...other imports

import {useFonts} from 'expo-font'

export default function App() {
  const [loadedFont] = useFonts({
    'poppins-regular' : "./src/assets/fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf",
    "poppins-bold" : "./src/assets/fonts/Poppins-Bold.ttf",
    "poppins-semiBold" : "./src/assets/fonts/Poppins-SemiBold.ttf",
  });
 

  return(
    <AuthProvider>
      <SafeAreaProvider style={{
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        }}>
          <Text style={{
            fontFamily: fonts["poppins-regular"],
            fontSize: 20,
            }}>
            Hello world
          </Text>
      </SafeAreaProvider>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}
```

Paths are correct, names of fonts aswell. When I try to use familyFont i receive console warning `..assets/fonts/Poppins-SemiBold.ttf is not a system font and has not been loaded through expo-font`

What should I do ?

Comment: What does it mean ? So they can be invalid ? I just downloaded them from any github profile. They are ttf files, but im going to download them from google and check once again.

Comment: I  checked, and it did not fix

Answer (score 2):

Try this, with "require":

```
    export default function App() {
      const [loaded, error] = useFonts({
        PoppinsRegular: require("./src/assets/fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf"),
        PoppinsBold: require("./src/assets/fonts/Poppins-Bold.ttf"),
        PoppinsSemiBold: require("./src/assets/fonts/Poppins-SemiBold.ttf"),
      });
     
useEffect(() => {
    if (error) throw error;
  }, [error]);

  
    
      return(loaded && 
        (<AuthProvider>
          <SafeAreaProvider style={{
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: "#fff",
            }}>
              <Text style={{
                fontFamily: "PoppinsRegular",
                fontSize: 20,
                }}>
                Hello world
              </Text>
          </SafeAreaProvider>
        </AuthProvider>)
      );
    }
```

Comment: it didn't help. Still while starting project get same warn

Comment: I edited my answer, please copy and paste my snippet.
You may only load the app content, after fonts are loaded.